# {unicode-bidi: bidi-override} + @Keyframes /*doesn't work except Chrome*/

Tags: html, css, safari, microsoft-edge

```css
a:link {
  color: #000000;
  -webkit-animation: Rev1 1s infinite;
  -ms-animation: Rev1 1s infinite;
  animation: Rev1 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Rev1 {
  50% {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  }
}

@-ms-Keyframes Rev1 {
  50% {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  }
}

@Keyframes Rev1 {
  50% {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

hello. I'm absolutely beginner and need your help.

i want to make my links animate. I checked it works at Chrome, but not at Edge, Safari.

please help me!